# PN532 Sensor Input without Microcontroller

Tags: nfc, sensors, temperature

I am attempting to build a component that will be able to transmit simple sensory data input (e.g. temperature) over NFC without the use of a microcontroller. In other words, just an NFC module and sensors powered by a battery. I am interested in the PN532 NFC module (specifically [this board](http://www.adafruit.com/product/789)) since it is quite popular, and I was wondering if anyone has had experience with this hardware and knows if my goal is possible?

I know NFC is capable of transmitting simple stored data when acting as a "card", but I would like to transmit a few bytes of dynamic data. I also know that this PN532 chip is capable of working in "card emulation" mode, but I believe this only allows the device to transmit information programmed in ROM.

If anyone can provide advice or point me towards another NFC module that would serve my purposes better, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question is "too broad" as it currently stands. You might have better luck at the [Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I worked with that board, however you will need a microcontroller, cause you will need to create the NDEF messages that you would like to send, like your temperature. I used it together with a netduino and arduino boards, that specific module you have linked is a shield ment for just put on top of those types of devices and you could use an interface like SPI to communicate with it, it has 2 more interfaces however i forgot what those are. Only really used the SPI part.